# Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I tried to figure out what is wrong with the code but couldnt find the cause. As the topic stated, it is caused by android.os.RemoteException. The app for sure could run smoothly in the emulator, but when I tried run on Huawei Nova 4e, it crash when opening this activity.

```
public class Engineerproofimage extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView previewimage;
    String uri;
    /*FireBase Auth*/
    FirebaseUser LoggedUser;

    /*Firebase RTDatabase*/
    FirebaseDatabase FirebaseDB;
    DatabaseReference DBRef;
    DatabaseReference UserName;
    DatabaseReference UserWorkerID;

    /*Firebase Storage*/
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageRef;
    StorageReference ProfilePicRef;

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    CustomPager MainvPager;

    ArrayList<GalleryModel> allimages;
    ArrayList<String> allkeys;
    VPAdapterE vpAdapter;
    CustomScrollView scrollpager;
    String MONTH;
    String MONTHint;
    String Dateset;
    String Key;
    String UID;

    TextView tvinfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_engineerproofimage);
        /*Initialize Firebase User Information*/
        LoggedUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (LoggedUser != null) {
            /*Name, Email Adress, Profile Pic
            For this prototype, the usage of gmail account are been taken,
            so all the information of the user are based on details from
            the gmail account.*/

            /*Initialize User Details*/
            String Name = LoggedUser.getDisplayName();
            String Email = LoggedUser.getEmail();
            String uID = LoggedUser.getUid();

            /*Initialize Firebase Storage*/
            storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            storageRef = storage.getReference();
            ProfilePicRef = storageRef.child("ProfilePicture/" + uID);

            /*Initialize Firebase Database*/
            FirebaseDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://fyp-project-e6826-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app");
            DBRef = FirebaseDB.getReference("Users/");
            Log.d("REF1", DBRef.toString());

        }


        MainvPager = findViewById(R.id.vpager);
        allimages = new ArrayList<>();
        allkeys = new ArrayList<>();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
        MONTH = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat month_int = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        MONTHint = month_int.format(cal.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Dateset = simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Key = intent.getExtras().getString("KEYINDV");
        UID = intent.getExtras().getString("UIDE");

        if (Key != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(Key)) {
            allkeys.clear();
            allimages.clear();
            try {
                GetImage(Key, UID);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }

    private void GetImage(String keys, String uid) {
        DatabaseReference PutUri = DBRef.child(uid).child("JOBS").child("Gallery").child(MONTH);

        PutUri.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapss : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = snapss.getKey();

                    String sub = key.substring(0, 3);
                    Log.d("testengineer", sub);

                    if (IRCorTaskCard(Engineerproofimage.this).equals("TASKCARD")){
                        if (key.contains(keys) && !sub.contains("IRC")){

                            String name = snapss.child("Name").getValue(String.class);

                            String ImageUri = snapss.child("Uri").getValue(String.class);
                            String date = snapss.child("Date").getValue(String.class);
                            String time = snapss.child("Time").getValue(String.class);
                            String location = snapss.child("Location").getValue(String.class);


                            allimages.add(new GalleryModel(ImageUri, name,
                                    date, time, location));

                            vpAdapter = new VPAdapterE(Engineerproofimage.this, allimages);
                            MainvPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
                            int prevpos = GalleryAdapter.getpos();
                            MainvPager.setCurrentItem(prevpos);
                        }

                    } else if (IRCorTaskCard(Engineerproofimage.this).equals("IRC")){
                        if (key.contains(keys) && sub.contains("IRC")){

                            String name = snapss.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                            String ImageUri = snapss.child("Uri").getValue(String.class);
                            String date = snapss.child("Date").getValue(String.class);
                            String time = snapss.child("Time").getValue(String.class);
                            String location = snapss.child("Location").getValue(String.class);


                            allimages.add(new GalleryModel(ImageUri, name,
                                    date, time, location));

                            vpAdapter = new VPAdapterE(Engineerproofimage.this, allimages);
                            MainvPager.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
                            int prevpos = GalleryAdapter.getpos();
                            MainvPager.setCurrentItem(prevpos);

                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image not found.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }





                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public class VPAdapterE extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<GalleryModel> imagelist;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        GalleryModel item;
        private int Position;

        public VPAdapterE(Context context, ArrayList<GalleryModel> imagelist) {
            this.context = context;
            this.imagelist = imagelist;
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imagelist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return view == o;
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View itemv = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.vpageritem, container, false);
            TouchImageView imageView = itemv.findViewById(R.id.imagevitem);
            FrameLayout frameLayout = itemv.findViewById(R.id.framee);

            TextView tvname = itemv.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            TextView tvdate = itemv.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            TextView tvtime = itemv.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            TextView tvlocation = itemv.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

            item = imagelist.get(position);

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            /*scrollView.setFocusable(false);*/
            frameLayout.getLayoutParams().width = width;
            frameLayout.getLayoutParams().height = height;

            LottieAnimationView loadanim = itemv.findViewById(R.id.loadselected);
            loadanim.setRepeatCount(LottieDrawable.INFINITE);
            loadanim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadanim.playAnimation();

            Position = position;

            tvname.setText(":" + item.getText());
            tvdate.setText(":" + item.getDate());
            tvtime.setText(":" + item.getTime());
            tvlocation.setText(":" + item.getLocation());

            Picasso.get().load(item.getImage_id()).fetch();
            Picasso.get().load(item.getImage_id()).into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    loadanim.pauseAnimation();
                    loadanim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    loadanim.pauseAnimation();
                    loadanim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to load images.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Objects.requireNonNull(container).addView(itemv);
            return itemv;


        }

        public Integer getJobPos() {
            return Position;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((CustomScrollView) object);
        }
    }

    public String IRCorTaskCard(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String checker = prefs.getString("WhatIsIt", "TASKCARD");
        return checker;
    }
}
```

and here is its stack trace.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fypproject2021, PID: 6437
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File descriptors passed in Bundle
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2075)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2039)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1987)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4566)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.activityStopped(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1873)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityTaskManager.java:2033)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1028)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1001)
```

Thank you in advance and for sure I will upvote the correct answer.